# How to make ChildViewController appear and disappear on same button action

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am using a childView Controller to show a set of options/varieties on navigation bar via button, When i click on the button ,childview appears and on the same button click i want to remove the childview. Plz help Thanks in advance.

Here is code

```
UIViewController * topViewController = navigationControllerGlobal.topViewController; 
childViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"childViewStoryboardId"];
self.myParentViewController = topViewController;
[topViewController addChildViewController:childViewController] childViewController.view.frame= self.myParentViewController.view.frame ; 
[topViewController.view addSubview:childViewController.view]; 
[childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:topViewController];
```

Comment: How you are adding childViewController, can you provide code for same?

Comment: you can set a bool variable for the child view. manage bool on hide and show of view.

Comment: 'UIViewController * topViewController = navigationControllerGlobal.topViewController;
        childViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"childViewStoryboardId"];
    self.myParentViewController = topViewController;
    [topViewController addChildViewController:childViewController];
    childViewController.view.frame= self.myParentViewController.view.frame ;
    [topViewController.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
    [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:topViewController];' @BharatModi

Comment: Not getting your problem, and please add above code in your answer.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what i understand bit from it is you want to display a ViewController on click of button and at the same time you also want to dismiss that ViewController by clicking on the same button, am i correct?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tomohisa/2897676 This link can help you. Add a boolean in your button function to know if child controller is added in the view or not.

Comment: thanx @Pipiks i tried something different .. and it worked i.e NSNotificationCenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer guys,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"removeChildNotify" object:navigationControllerGlobal.topViewController]
```